The commutation relations of photon and gluon?
In QED, the photon field has the following commutation relations:
\begin{equation}
[A^{\mu}(t,\vec{x}),A^{\nu}(t,\vec{y})]=0,   \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $A^{\mu}(t,\vec{x})$ is the photon filed. As for QCD, I can not find  similar relations for gluon, can we have
\begin{equation}
[A_a^{\mu}(t,\vec{x}),A_a^{\nu}(t,\vec{y})]=0  \, \, \,  \, \,  (2)
\end{equation}
for gluon field with color index $a$? Or do we have the following equation
\begin{equation}
[A_a^{\mu}(t,\vec{x}),A_a^{\nu}(t,\vec{x})]=0  \, \, \,   \, \,  (3)
\end{equation}
for gluon at same $x$? From the definition of gluon field-strength tensor
\begin{equation}
F^{\mu \nu}=\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}-\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu}-ig[A^{\mu},A^{\nu}],  \, \, \,   \, \,  (4)
\end{equation}
where $A^{\mu}=A_a^{\mu}t^a$,  the last term of Eq.(4) is often reexpressed as
\begin{equation}
[A^{\mu},A^{\nu}]=A_a^{\mu}A_b^{\nu}t^a t^b-A_b^{\nu}A_a^{\mu}t^bt^a=A_a^{\mu}A_b^{\nu} [t^a, t^b].\, \, \,   \, \,  (5)
\end{equation}
Does Eq.(5) implies that
\begin{equation}
A_a^{\mu}A_b^{\nu}=A_b^{\nu}A_a^{\mu} \, \, \,   \, \,  (6)
\end{equation}
thus gluon commutes at the same position. Could someone tell me which of the above equations are not correct, or how do we understand the commutation relations  of gluon?

It would be nice if you referenced (1); the ET commutator vanishes because the structure of coefficients of the constituent oscillators lacks the "interesting snag" of canonically conjugate fields. (Practice with scalar QFT first, abelian and non-abelian). The interesting pieces, however, are the ones involving fields and field momenta, which contain the singularities... Do you want an answer for scalar fields, eschewing the irrelevant complexities?

Thanks very much, Eq.(1) is from Eq.(6.93b) of the book "Field quantization, greiner", what am I interested is the hadronic matrix element of  the vector field $A^{\mu} A^{\nu}$, I guess that singularities do not contribute?

I don't have his book, but,  indeed, there are no equal time singularities, for the analogous reason there are no φφ ones... The singularities emerge for combinations of a field with its canonical conjugate...

Since, the fields decouple for different colors, the analog of (1) is (2), where the color indices a are not summed over. Again, singularities only emerge for canonical momentum  involvement, the analog of (6.93a). With the suitable equal time indices inserted, (6) comports with (2).

Thanks very much for your comment, Eq. (6) is equal time commutation, and I also find two papers on the gluon commutation relations, they are: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.1.2901; https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.8.2736. I am studing those papers now, and it seems that the commutation relations are complicated for gluons.

But you do realize that light-cone commutators are not equal time ones, no?

Yes, in the papers they are light-cone commutators, in Eq.(6) the spacetime coordinate is same.

@CosmasZachos is there a formulation of QCD using forces, similar to $\vec F = q (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$, instead of using Lagrangians? E.g. what is the magnitude and direction of the force that a red up quark exerts on a green down quark given their respective position and momentum?

The force equation you write is of classical electrodynamics, not QED, a QFT. QCD is a "pure" (infrared-enslaving) QFT and has no sensible classical limit, on account of confinement.
